Why won't my dynamic DDL procedure in Oracle 19c run?
I'm trying to create a procedure that will create a table based on the dates provided as arguments.
The procedure seems good to go, but when I attempt to run it, I get "ORA-00904: "END_DATE": invalid identifier".
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl_sp (begin_date nvarchar2, end_date nvarchar2) AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
    CREATE TABLE
            sao_eligible_members_tbl AS
    SELECT
        h.pay_order_date
        FROM
            clm_header_h h
        WHERE
            TO_CHAR( h.pay_order_date, 'YYYYMM' ) BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date
    ]';
END ddl_sp;
/


BEGIN
    ddl_sp('202301', '202401');
END;

Please don't ask about why the dates are the way they are; it wasn't my choice. They work.


Why won't my dynamic DDL procedure in Oracle 19c run?

Because the statement ran via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE runs in a different scope to the PL/SQL procedure and does not have access to PL/SQL scope so begin_date and end_date are not defined.

You would normally use a USING clause of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement to pass the arguments into bind variables in the query; however, you cannot use bind variables in DDL statements so you either need to:

Create the table first and then insert the data
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl_sp (begin_date nvarchar2, end_date nvarchar2) AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE sao_eligible_members_tbl (pay_order_date DATE)';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[INSERT INTO sao_eligible_members_tbl
      SELECT pay_order_date
      FROM   clm_header_h
      WHERE  pay_order_date >= TO_DATE(:1, 'YYYYMM')
      AND    pay_order_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:2, 'YYYYMM'), 1)
    ]' USING begin_date, end_date;
END ddl_sp;
/

or

Concatenate the date strings into the query:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl_sp (begin_date nvarchar2, end_date nvarchar2) AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
    CREATE TABLE sao_eligible_members_tbl AS
      SELECT pay_order_date
      FROM   clm_header_h
      WHERE  pay_order_date >= TO_DATE(']' || begin_date || q'[', 'YYYYMM')
      AND    pay_order_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(']' || end_date || q'[', 'YYYYMM'), 1)
    ]';
END ddl_sp;
/

If you are going to build the query using string concatenation then ensure you sanitise your inputs so you do not suffer from SQL injection attacks.


fiddle

Excellent  answer. Thank you very much!
